# Command Line FTP Client Confused By Tilde?

Tags: terminal, ftp

I noticed this really weird behaviour in the macOS command line ftp client...

```
get index.html ~/Desktop/index.html
```

fails if there exists no 'index.html' on the Desktop with the error

```
ftp: Can't access `~/Desktop/index.html': No such file or directory
```

but

```
get index.html /Users/fweth/Desktop/index.html
```

succeeds!  Afterwards, I can also use the first command to update the local file.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### **What you are seeing is expected behavior.**

The [tilde](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) (~) is a part of the shell's standard syntax that is synonymous with the user's home directory.

> Tilde expansion is the process of converting these abbreviations to
> the directory names that they stand for.

When you are in FTP, you are not using your shell (bash, csh, zsh, etc.), rather you are using the FTP client and it has no idea what the tilde means and thusly, it cannot expand it out.

`~` and `HOME` are the same thing.  If you execute the command

```
$ echo ~ $HOME
```

You should get your home directory output twice.  (The `$` is for variable expansion)

```
/Users/fweth /Users/fweth
```

#### Trivia

The convention of using the tilde (~) derives from the [Lear Siegler ADM-3A terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A) that had a keyboard shortcut for the the users' HOME on the same key as the tilde.

[image]

Comment: I see, but the funny thing is that after the file has been created, I *can* access it via the tilde notation, also from within the ftp client...  But thanks a lot for the detailed answer.